# Re-dimensioning javascript arrays (i.e 1x6 => 2x3)

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, multidimensional-array

Is it possible to use a higher order javascript function to resize single dimension array into a multi-dimensional array (i.e. 1x6 to 2x3) or do i have to work around with for loops?

Do you have any code examples to resize `[0,1,2,3,4,5]` to `[[0,1,2],[3,4,5]]`?

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any function that could resize an array the way you want. You need to to that with loops, I could write an example code that contains loops if you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a real 2D array, you could flat it and take the values with a generator by using new arrays' mapping.

```js
function resize(array, i, j) {
    var gen = array.reduce((a, b) => a.concat(b))[Symbol.iterator]();
    
    return Array.from({ length: i }, _ => Array.from({ length: j }, _ => gen.next().value));
}

console.log(resize([[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]], 2, 3));
```

Comment: Cheers Nina!!! It works really really well. Thankyou sooo much 

Answer (score -1):

Using Ramda https://ramdajs.com/docs/#splitEvery

```
R.splitEvery(3, [0,1,2,3,4,5]); //=> [[0,1,2],[3,4,5]]
```

Comment: How does this not answer the question?

Comment: Possibly because it is not showing any code but is relying on a library to perform something trivial. I did not vote down but I can see why

Comment: @mplugjan makes sense, but that Nina Scholz answer is clearly non-trivial lol

Comment: That is because it is Nina. Is this better: `var i,j,temparray,chunk = 3;
for (i=0,j=array.length; i<j; i+=chunk) {
    temparray = array.slice(i,i+chunk);
    // do whatever
}`

Comment: @mplungjan, "*That is because it is Nina.*" do i miss something?

Comment: You always post highly effective but impossible for any noob to decipher- because you can. More power to you. The code from the dupe I posted in the comment  above is much easier to read and does the same.